# Cloning ec2 linux instance on aws in local environment

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a production server running on AWS ec2 instance. Since I was a beginner when I started everything I hadn't use virtual env etc.

Now, there are many dependencies and packages that I have installed somehow. Is there a way to clone entire AWS ec2 instance environment with all the packages into my local machine for dev work. I know from pip freeze I can get all the python dependencies (I have a running Django server). But is there a way to clone everything (from docker etc.).

Comment: Is this maybe what you're looking for? https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/ If not, you might be interested in just looking up on importing ec2 images in VirtualBoxes, and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon VM Import/Export service is there to export images from EC2 instances. However this doesn't fit your use case due to the following [limitation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html#vmexport-limits) of the VM Import/Export service.

> You can't export an instance from Amazon EC2 unless you previously
>   imported it into Amazon EC2 from another virtualization environment.

Note: For details on steps to export previously imported virtual machine images, have a look at the user guide on [Exporting an Instance as a VM Using VM Import/Export](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html).

Comment: You cannot export an EC2 instance unless you originally imported it into AWS.

Comment: @John Your point is valid. Will update the answer for future reference. Thanks!